# FCM Flutter Android Does Not Show Heads Up or Making a Sound When Installed

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I'm Trying to use FCM For My App To Send And Receive Notification and it's a major part of my app.
the problem I'm facing is when the app (android version) gets installed on (Emulator, Device) it does not show the heads up notification or makes a sound.
this my app settings when installed
[image]
and this is my channel.
[image]

```
 static Future initFireBase() async {
await Firebase.initializeApp();

NotificationSettings settings = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(
  alert: true,
  announcement: false,
  badge: true,
  carPlay: false,
  criticalAlert: false,
  provisional: false,
  sound: true,
);

if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
  print('User granted permission');
} else if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
  print('User granted provisional permission');
} else {
  print('User declined or has not accepted permission');
}
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);

var token  = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
log('Token $token', name: _className);

FirebaseMessaging.instance.onTokenRefresh.listen((newToken) {
  log('New Token $newToken', name: _className);

});


//it opens the app if terminated on notification tap
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) async {
  if (message != null) {
    await LocalNotificationHandler.displayNotification(message);
    message.data.forEach((key, value) {
    });
  }
});

//foreground notification
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
  // Works and displays
  log('foreground onMessage', name: _className);

  if (message.notification != null) {
    log('title ${message.notification!.title}', name: _className);
    log('body ${message.notification!.body}', name: _className);
  }
  LocalNotificationHandler.displayNotification(message);
});

//Background but alive
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
  log('Background onMessageOpenedApp', name: _className);
  log('data ${message.data.toString()}', name: _className);
});
```

}

this code does not show me the permission request on android so as i understand it's implemented for IOS only and it prints 'User granted permission' as default.

```
 if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      print('User granted permission');
    } else if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
      print('User granted provisional permission');
    } else {
      print('User declined or has not accepted permission');
    }
```

And Here is the local Notification Plugin code for displaying notification on Foreground

```
class LocalNotificationHandler {
  static const String _className = 'Local Notification Handler';
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _localNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static void initialize() {
    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
      android: AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher'),
    );
    _localNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,onSelectNotification: (String? data) async{
      if(data != null){
        log('_localNotificationsPlugin data $data', name: _className);
      }
    });
  }

  static Future<void> displayNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
    try {
      final id = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;
      NotificationDetails notificationDetails = const NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          //realestateid
          'realestateid', //channel id
          'realestate channel', //channel name
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.high,
          playSound: true,

        ),
        iOS: IOSNotificationDetails(
          presentAlert: true,
          presentBadge: true,
          presentSound: true,
        )
      );

      await _localNotificationsPlugin.show(id, message.notification!.title,
          message.notification!.body, notificationDetails,payload: message.data['route']);
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      log('display Notification Exception $e', name: _className);
    }
  }
}
```

and initializing both of them in main.dart file

```
   //the top level func for terminated state
      await LocalNotificationHandler.displayNotification(message);

void main()async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  //FCM Notifications
  LocalNotificationHandler.initialize();
  await FCMNotification.initFireBase();
}
```

so if anyone could help me with this it'll be really appreciated.
thanks in advance and sorry for the long post.

Comment: There are three states of app i.e Background/Foreground/Termintated. In which state are you facing this issue?

Comment: @BilalSaeed
all of them. the code works fine but it needs permission to enable sounds and heads up notification, which when tested on android is granted but not set on the first time installing.
so my issue is who to ensure permission is granted on android and even if not how to know.

Comment: @BilalSaeed should i close the question

Comment: Your question needs long conversation. I don't know whether I should share my contact details here or not as it might be against the stack overflow community guidelines.

Comment: @BilalSaeed
Could you mention an article or anything that could help me?
and if u could mention the issues with my code in summary so I can be aware of it atleast.

Comment: come to this chat-room and we can sort this out there.
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/246473/flutter-firebase-fcm

Comment: @BilalSaeed
Thanks for your concern.
Could you please choose a date so we can meet up?

Comment: @BilalSaeed 
Hello again .

Comment: Contact on whatsapp +923058431046

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out in my case was the issue with the emulator, but with real devices it works fine.